# Editing Background Image

Tags: html, css, image, background

[image: Home Page Screenshot]

I need to do a few things to fix my background.

1.) I need to move it over to the right so that it lines up perfectly with the horizontal navigation bar and the pictures below it.
2.) I need to move it down so that won't be seen at all above the horizontal navigation bar.

The background image is just the brown circles with white circles inside them (seen on the right).

Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

#banner {width:100%}
#banner img {width:100%;height:auto}

nav {width:100%;display:block;}
nav ul {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
background-color:#c0872e;}
nav li {display:inline-block;background-color:
#c0872e;font family:Georgia;}
nav a {line-height:35px; color:white; padding: 0 30px; font-size:22px;
font-family:Georgia; background-color:#c0872e;}
nav a:hover {text-decoration:none}

a{float:left;
margin-right:58px;
margin-left:58px;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

body {background-image: url("daikinbackground1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
}

-->
</style>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>daikininc.com</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="body">
<header>
<div>
<div style="text-align:center" id="banner">
<title="daikinincbanner">
<img src="daikinbanner1.jpg" border="0" alt="daikinbanner1">
</div>
<!--
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
-->
<nav style="text-align:center">
<img style ="height:300px" width="1355" src="navbarimage1.jpg">
</nav>
<br>
<p style="text-align:center;font-family:WindsorDemi;">
<font size="4">
Welcome to daikininc.com! Home to the world's greatest 
eggorll wrappers and noodles.
</font>
</p>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

</nav>
</header>

<section>
<aside>
</aside>
<article>
</article>

<footer>
</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: could I get a link to the site?

Comment: The site isn't hosted yet, and what you see in the image is all I have so far.

Comment: it was really to just get some more depth to your code what you've provided doesn't really give anything workable.

Comment: Hopefully that helps. I tried adding margin-right and margin-left spacing after "background-position" in the css, but this only moved everything else left or right - not the background image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
body {background-image: url("daikinbackground1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 126px 50px;}
```

background-position controls x and y coordinates for background image.